# Force an iOS app (Ad Hoc distribution) to stop working after some time

Tags: ios, adhoc

Which would be the best approach to prevent that an app could be used after some days of "testing"? Lets say I have to distribute my app using Ad Hoc distribution, the user has only one week to test, after that he should not be able to use the app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the risk? That your beta testers won't buy the real thing? How many of them do you have? By the way, I've found out that the promise of getting a release candidate for free is a good motivation for beta testers. In other words, don't be stingy and let them use it.

Comment: Seva, totally agree with you. Unfortunately, I have orders to do it that way.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev There is a big difference between letting a user keep using an old beta and giving them a free copy of the final release. There are valid reason to make a beta expire. I always give my testers free copies of the final release version but I don't want them using old betas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do the following to put a time limit in the app for beta testing:

```
#ifdef BETA
    NSString *compileDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s %s", __DATE__, __TIME__];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [df setLocale:usLocale];
    NSDate *aDate = [df dateFromString:compileDate];
    NSDate *expires = [aDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60 * 60 * 24 * 7]; // 7 days
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    if ([now compare:expires] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        NSAssert(0, @"Sorry, expired");
    }
#endif
```

where `BETA` is a compile flag I set only for adhoc builds.

I put this code in the `applicationWillEnterForeground:` app delegate method.

Comment: Conceivably, the user could set back the date and still use the app. You could have a resource you delete at expiration time, but a full reinstall would restore it.  Might be best to have the app call a time server to get the real time, and disable itself on that condition.

Comment: Looks great, I'll give it a try using a short value (5 minutes). After that I will be glad to accept your answer

Comment: @OwenHartnett It's always a balance. This solution is simple. Replacing the call to `[NSDate date]` with a call to an NTP server is another level of complexity.

Comment: @OwenHartnett you are right about set time back, however I think this is enough for the requirement I have. The solution you propose is more complete, and more time consuming to implement

Comment: It all depends on how bad you want those betas to never be used.

Comment: @maddy I'm testing your solution. Works ok when app is in background, but when you kill the app and start again works ok. What about to put this same code in applicationDidBecomeActive as well ?

Comment: @aprunedamtz Yeah, I suppose that would be a better place.

Comment: One problem with this method is that the compileDate is only updated when *that* file is compiled.  This file will only get compiled after a clean build or when you change something in that file.  It is not compiled every time you build the app.

Comment: @progrmr I always do a clean build for an adhoc release as well as a distribution release. This ensures that no stale or deleted files/resources end up in the build. It also ensure the code in this answer is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Every time an app is built by Xcode, it creates a file `Info.plist` in the app's bundle.  We can get the modification date from that file to determine how long it has been since it was built.

```
#if BETA
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    const NSTimeInterval kExpirationAge = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;   // 7 days

    NSString* infoPlistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Info" ofType: @"plist"];
    NSDictionary* fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:infoPlistPath error:NULL];
    NSDate* buildDate = (NSDate*) [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];
    const NSTimeInterval buildAge = -[buildDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

    if (buildAge > kExpirationAge) {
        UIAlertView* av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App Expired"
                                                     message:@"This version is expired.  Please update to the latest version of this app."
                                                    delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [av show];

        // after 10 seconds the app exits
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            exit(0);
        });
    }
}
#endif
```